# Use array elements as names of the variables i want to read to from a file

Tags: arrays, bash, list, csv, parsing

I know that reading a .csv file can be done simply in bash with this loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=data.cvs
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read flname dob ssn tel status
do
    echo "Name : $flname"
    echo "DOB : $dob"
    echo "SSN : $ssn"
    echo "Telephone : $tel"
    echo "Status : $status"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

But I want to slightly modify this- I want to make the columns be defined by the programmer in the bash file.
For example:

```
declare -a columns=("Name", "Surname", "ID", "Gender")
while read columns
    do
        //now echo everything that has been read
done < $INPUT
```

So I want to specify the list of variables that should be used as the container to the read CSV data with an array and then access this array inside the while body.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Commas are not element separators; the first element of your array is the literal string `Name,`, not `Name`.

Comment: Keep in mind that CSV files can contain quoted commas as part of a field, which `bash` can't really handle. Use a language with a proper CSV parser rather than hacking together a fragile quasiparser in `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this solution is the comment before the `while` statement below. `read` is a built-in, but it is still a command, and command arguments are expanded by the shell before executing the command. After expansion of `${columns[@]}`, the command becomes

```
read Name Surname ID Gender
```

Example:

```
# Don't use commas in between array values (since they become part of the value)
# Values not quoted because valid names don't need quotes, and these
# value must be valid names
declare -a columns=(Name Surname ID Gender)
```

Then, we can try:

```
# Read is a command. Arguments are expanded.
# The quotes are unnecessary but it's hard to break habits :)
while read "${columns[@]}"; do
  echo Name is "$Name"
  # etc
done <<< "John Doe 27 M"
```

Output:

```
Name is John
```

This same approach would work even in a shell without arrays; the column names can just be a space separated list. (Example run in dash, a Posix shell)

```
$ columns="Name Surname ID Gender"
$ # Here it is vital that $columns not be quoted; we rely on word-splitting
$ while read $columns; do 
> echo Name is $Name
> done 
John Doe 27 M
Name is John

...
```

Comment: @chepner: if the arguments need to be quoted, it won't work because they will be invalid names. Although I guess it doesn't really hurt.

Comment: Better to be consistent and clear that the sole purpose of the `@` forms is to *be* quoted; if it doesn't need to be quoted, there's no reason to use it over the corresponding `*` form. (And if you are being paranoid, quoting guards against an alphabetic character having been added to `IFS`.)

Comment: @chepner: I put the quotes back (although you're right; I could have used `[*]` to signal intent) and added a non-array example, necessarily without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Read the line into an array, then loop through that array and create an associative array that uses the column names.

```
while read -r line
do
    vals=($line)
    declare -A colmap
    i=0
    for col in ${columns[@]}
    do
        colmap[col]=${vals[$i]}
        let i=i+1
    done
    # do stuff with colmap here
    # ...
    unset colmap # Clear colmap before next iteration
done < $INPUT
```