# bash - mapping a variable header when reading CSV

Tags: bash, csv

I need to parse the content of a CSV file, that changes on its content, without any advise about. Therefore, sometimes I'll receive a file with this content:

"No,Latitude,Longitude,Name,Altitude,Satellites,Date,Time"

and some others with this..

"No,Latitude,Longitude,Name,Altitude,Date,Time"

or maybe other (always with the same content.. but sometimes 5 columns.. some others 6 columns... etc. I mean.. sometimes I miss Name.. or Satellites... or both)

Therefore.. I need to read and understand what is inside of each column for elaborating a fixed CSV with (always) the same content:

"No,Latitude,Longitude,Name,Altitude,Satellites,Date,Time"

In order to do that I was thinking on:

1. Read the header and assign some values to each column:

`IFS=",";read -r a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4] a[5] a[6] a[7] a[8] a[9] a[10] a[11]`

This is for reading the header

Same process for the header I need to create (the one I know):

`IFS=",";read -r b[1] b[2] b[3] b[4] b[5] b[6] b[7] <<< "No,Latitude,Longitude,Name,Altitude,Satellites,Date,Time"`

2. Run a loop for each non empty values of the A array.. trying to match any of the headers of B array

```
do

for x in [1..7]

do

if [[ ${a[i]} = ${b[x]} ]] 

then

# The column i from my source file belongs to the column x of my output file 

output[$x]=$i

fi

done

done
```

3. Store this on my new file.. with something like this.

```
IFS=","; while read -r a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4] a[5] a[6] a[7] a[8] a[9] a[10] a[11]

do
 
echo "${a[output[1]]}, ${a[output[2]]},${a[output[3]]},${a[output[4]]},${a[output[5]]},${a[output[6]]},${a[output[7]]}" >> new.csv

done < source.csv
```

I think this should work since it will record the appropriated source column into the desired final column....

But.. I'm sure that there are many ways easier and more elegant for doing this..

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: if name and satellites are both missing, as you say, then where are you reading their values?

Comment: what's the ultimate objective ... add a null/empty field for 'missing' columns, with the intention being to end up with a final csv that has, what, 7 total columns?

Comment: Are the column headings valid shell variable names? If so, KamilCuk's answer to ["How to process all or selected rows in a csv file where column headers and order are dynamic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895328#55899356) (mostly the first part) might work (though I'd recommend using a plain redirect, instead of piping from `cat`). Also see rici's answer to ["Use array elements as names of the variables i want to read to from a file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729979#50730881).

Comment: the main idea is not produce a truncated CSV. I need that in any case latitude, longitude and time there, but the rest.. are not really relevant. If one of those values are missing, i can paste a 0 o a null.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. I'll review KamilCuk's answer

Comment: it would help if you provided a sample input file and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  possesses the `template` *verb* for exactly this kind of task:

> **mlr template [options]**
>      Places input-record fields in the order specified by list of column names.
>      If the input record is missing a specified field, it will be filled with the *fill-with*.
>      If the input record possesses an unspecified field, it will be discarded. 
> **Options:**
>      `-f {a,b,c}` Comma-separated field names for template.
>      `-t {filename}` CSV file whose header line will be used for template.
>      `--fill-with {filler string}` What to fill absent fields with. Defaults to the empty string.

So you could do:

```bash
mlr --csv template \
    -f 'No,Latitude,Longitude,Name,Altitude,Satellites,Date,Time' \
    --fill-with '0' \
    file.csv
```

Or use the header of an other file as reference:

```bash
mlr --csv template -t header.csv --fill-with '0' file.csv
```